# Java Finding number of occurrences of a string in another string using nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I'm new to programming. I'm using java. Right now I have an assignment I can't solve on a website that teaches java.

This is the assignment

Write a program that  returns number of occurrences of a string in another string.

E.g

Input:

First String: the

Second String: The children are playing with their toys because they love it.

Output:

3

Note: You should only use nested loops. Don’t use  methods like indexOf or substring.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String a = input.nextLine();
String b = input.nextLine();
String z[]  = b.split(" ");
int number=0;
for (int i =0; i<z.length; i++){

if (z[i].contains(a))number++;  


}
System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: Go ahead and edit that into your main question. Comments do a terrible, terrible job of formatting, as you can see.

Comment: "Don’t use methods like indexOf or substring" might be a hint that you're supposed to write your own indexOf.

Comment: I don't think so . This is supposed to be an absolute beginner course. and all the other questions were very easy. May you check my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't give you too much code, but here are the main talking points:

- You need a way to read the input in.  This can be accomplished with a `Scanner` - it's either from STDIN or a file.
- You need a way to break up each word in the sentence.  `String#split` will help you with that.
- You need a way to ignore the casing of each sentence - `toLowerCase()` works well here.
- You need to loop over each word in one sentence, as well as each occurrence in the other sentence.  Consider that `String.split` produces a `String[]`, and you can iterate over that with any standard `for` loop.
- You need a way to see is a string is contained in another string.  `String#contains` will help - although you want to be very careful on which side you're asking contains a string.  For example:

  ```
  // This will print true
  System.out.println("The world".toLowerCase().contains("the"));
  // This will print false
  System.out.println("the".contains("The world".toLowerCase()));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm unfamiliar with String#split and String#contains. I'll read about them and see what I can do.

Comment: It worked. Actually turned out to be pretty simple code. Thanks

Comment: However when using stringsplit function I made it so that every space it will split. Now what if there are no spaces in the second string?

Comment: You'd get an array of size 1, which is fine, since it's representative of there only being one word in that sentence.

Comment: Yeah I mean if the first string is "the" and the second string is "themanisthehappiest ever". If I use stringsplit after each space it will make a string array with only 2 strings "themanisthehappiest" and "ever". So when it's time to check if String[0] contains the string "the", I will increment number by 1. But there are 2 occurences not just one. –

Comment: For the most part, the above is a guide to help you to an ideal solution.  The example you provided in your original question didn't include that scenario, but it's not hard to solve; consider that once you've split your string up into fragments, you can begin taking chunks of the substring of the larger string in and compare them against your smaller string.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. My bad. However that solution will still require using the substring method. Anyway, I guess I'm just going to ignore the course requirement that prevents using IndexOf or Substring. It seems like that is the only way to solve the problem using only arrays and nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Occurence {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 = input.nextLine();
        String str2 = input.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        String word[] = str1.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

            if (word[i].toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Occurence = " + count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've written the same code. It works well when there is a space between each word. Otherwise it doesn't. For example, if the first string is "themanisthebest" and my second string is "the". Although there are 2 occurrences of the second string "the". The program will count only 1 occurrences, since themanisthe is going to be stored as a single String in the word[]. So the program will check if themanisthe just contains "the" and since it does it will increment count by 1. However count should be incremented by 2 since there are 2 occurrences of "the" in "themanisthe".